# variable created in page.php is null inside of header.php

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

Ok, so i'm instantiating a class in page.php.

Then i'm calling `get_header()` to include header.php

now in header.php i need to access this class object and execute one of its methods but i get this error:

\nFatal error: Uncaught exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Call to a member function links() on a non-object (NULL)'

should i just use `require` instead of `get_header()` ?

Comment: No, you should use get_header() because of the way it interacts with the rest of WordPress, and will make your theme much easier for other developers to interact with.  If there is no alternate solution, you can just make the variable global.  I would try to conditionally check what template, page, etc is being loaded in header.php and then handle all the class instantiating there.

Answer (score 0):

Generally said, there should nothing be happening before the `get_header()` call.

So initiate your class if `is_page()` is `true` via `wp_head` action hook. Example:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'initiate_my_class' );
function initiate_my_class() {
    if ( is_page() ) {
        //code
    }
}
```

Edit: As @AndrewBartel in his [comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175201/variable-created-in-page-php-is-null-inside-of-header-php#comment255047_175201) said you can globalize your variable or implement some kind of storage system via the class or another one.